# Push Notification - Serviço próprio

Tags: react, react-native, mobile, websocket

Gostaria de saber se alguém já implementou um serviço de push notification próprio, se existe essa possibilidade.

Tenho um aplicativo em react native e vários serviços em nuvem que se comunicam por mensageria.

Gostaria de saber uma boa pratica de um serviço rodando em background poderia ficar escutando essas mensagens que consigo direcionar para os clientes e abrir um local notification.

Meus apps já tem conexão com websocket que poderia ser uma solução.

Alguém tem uma ideia boa, não queria usar serviços externos como OnSignal, Firebase, etc.